# How to get results from two tables with or without using joins?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get the following results. Please help with the Oracle SQL query.

Results:

```
ID | APP_NUMBER | DATE
1  | ABC4100 | 10/02/2016
11 | ABC1001 | 10/04/2016
34 | ABC2001 | 9/15/2016
```

The above results are obtained from the two tables below:

Table 1:

```
ROW | ID | APP_NUMBER | DATE
1   | 1  | ABC4000    | 01/01/2016
2   | 1  | ABC4100    | 01/02/2016
3   | 1  | ABC4100    | 01/03/2016
4   | 11 | ABC1001    | 04/01/2016
5   | 34 | ABC2001    | 05/01/2016
```

Table 2:

```
APP_NUMBER | DATE
ABC4000    | 01/01/2016
ABC4100    | 08/02/2016
ABC4100    | 09/15/2016
ABC4100    | 10/02/2016
ABC1001    | 10/01/2016
ABC1001    | 10/02/2016
ABC1001    | 10/03/2016
ABC1001    | 10/04/2016
ABC2001    | 09/14/2016
ABC2001    | 09/15/2016
```

Comment: The logic behind your needed result is not clear, please better explain it; besides, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Queue dozens of answers that will achieve the same thing, but not in the real world situation you are asking about... How do you define which date should be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id,
       app_number,
       "date" 
from (
      select distinct table_1.id,
            table_1.app_number,
            table_2."date" ,
            rank() over (partition by id order by table_2."date" desc) r
from  table_1,
      table_2
where table_1.APP_NUMBER=table_2.APP_NUMBER
)
where r=1
order by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the required result.

```
with table2(APP_NUMBER, DT) as (  select 'ABC4000',to_date ('01/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
                                  UNION ALL
                                  select 'ABC4100',to_date ('08/02/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
                                  UNION ALL
                                  select 'ABC4100',to_date ('09/15/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
                                  UNION ALL
                                  select 'ABC4100',to_date ( '10/02/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
                                  UNION ALL
                                  select 'ABC1001',to_date ( '10/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
                                  UNION ALL
                                  select 'ABC1001',to_date ('10/02/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
                                  UNION ALL
                                  select 'ABC1001',to_date ( '10/03/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
                                  UNION ALL
                                  select 'ABC1001',to_date ('10/04/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
                                  UNION ALL
                                  select 'ABC2001',to_date ( '09/14/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
                                  UNION ALL
                                  select 'ABC2001',to_date ( '09/15/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual ),
       table1(ROWN,ID,APP_NUMBER,DTE) as ( select '1', '1','ABC4000',to_date( '01/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual 
                                           UNION ALL
                                           select '2', '1','ABC4100',to_date( '01/02/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual 
                                           UNION ALL
                                           select '3', '1','ABC4100',to_date( '01/03/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual 
                                           UNION ALL
                                           select '4', '11','ABC1001',to_date( '04/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual 
                                           UNION ALL
                                           select '5', '34','ABC2001',to_date( '05/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual 
                                          )

select max(t1.id),t2.app_number,max(t2.dt)
from    table2 t2
inner join  table1 t1
ON t1.APP_NUMBER = t2.APP_NUMBER
where t1.APP_NUMBER <> 'ABC4000'
group by  t2.APP_NUMBER ,t1.id      
order by t1.id  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.APP_NUMBER, MAX(t2.Date)
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.APP_NUMBER = t2.APP_NUMBER
WHERE t1.APP_NUMBER IN ('ABC4100', 'ABC1001', 'ABC2001')
ORDER BY t1.ID
```

This should work, but you may want to try t2.APP_NUMBER if it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Try this-

```
SELECT ID,t1.APP_NUMBER,MAX(t2.Date)
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.APP_NUMBER=t2.APP_NUMBER
GROUP BY ID,t1.APP_NUMBER
```

Comment: This will not give the needed result

Answer (score -2):

You can use LEFT JOIN to join the result from two table as shown in the example below:

`Select * from Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t1.APP_NUMBER = t2.APP_NUMBER);`

Comment: This will not give the needed result